# My multithreaded code is giving wrong results and has segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a program that must take on command-line a file_name, a string string_name (word)  and an integer (number of threads) as arguments. Then the program creates those many threads to count the number of times string_name occurs in the file - file_name.

The serial code run properly.
The multithreaded code has following problems:

1. It leads to core dump - segmentation fault.
2. It is giving wrong count.

I added some debugging statements:

3. It is showing wrong line numbers where I am trying to print which line number is being checked by which thread number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <conio.h> - Does not exist in gcc
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 4096
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 64
#define MAX_THREAD_COUNT_PER_PROCESS 64

// Important - in GCC - for pthread functions in addition to include pthread.h must also use flag -lpthread in compilation command
// gcc -w -o main main_multithreaded.c -lpthread

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct {
                uint valid;
                uint line_num;
                char* line;
                } struct_line;

volatile struct_line buffer[MAX_THREAD_COUNT_PER_PROCESS];
pthread_mutex_t *buffer_mutex;

pthread_t* threads;

typedef struct {
                FILE* fp;
                } read_pthread_argv_type;
read_pthread_argv_type read_pthread_argv;

void read_file(void* read_pthread_argv)
{
    read_pthread_argv_type* i_read_pthread_argv;
    i_read_pthread_argv = (read_pthread_argv_type*) read_pthread_argv;
    FILE* local_file_ptr;
    local_file_ptr = i_read_pthread_argv->fp;

    char *line;
    uint i, line_count = 0, line_length;
    line = (char*) malloc (MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, local_file_ptr) != NULL)
    {
        line_length = strlen (line);
        while (pthread_mutex_lock(buffer_mutex))
        {}
        for (i = 0; i<MAX_THREAD_COUNT_PER_PROCESS; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i].valid != 1)
                {
                    break;
                }

        }
        buffer[i].line = (char*) malloc (line_length);
        buffer[i].line = line;
        buffer[i].line_num = line_count;
        buffer[i].valid = 1;
    //  printf ("Line %u of file read and saved as %s \n", buffer[i].line_num, buffer[i].line);
        line_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(buffer_mutex);
    }
    printf ("File read finished \n");

    free (line);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

typedef struct {
                char* string_to_search;
                uint thread_num;
                uint count;
                } count_pthread_argv_type;          
count_pthread_argv_type count_pthread_argv[MAX_THREAD_COUNT_PER_PROCESS];

int count_string (void* pthread_argv_i)
{

    // Declare variables for line and word
    char *line, *word; 
    line = (char*) malloc (MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    word = (char*) malloc (MAX_WORD_SIZE);

    // Declare and initiaize count
    uint count = 0, wordcount_in_line;
    uint i, k = 0;
    int j;

    count_pthread_argv_type* i_pthread_argv;
    i_pthread_argv = (count_pthread_argv_type*)pthread_argv_i;
    char* local_string_to_search = i_pthread_argv->string_to_search;
    uint local_thread_num = i_pthread_argv-> thread_num;
    //printf (" For thread %u -> Local string to search = %s \n starting line = %u and num_lines = %u \n", \
                local_thread_num, local_string_to_search, local_starting_line, local_num_lines);
    //getchar();


    while (1)
    {
        while (pthread_mutex_lock(buffer_mutex))
        {}
        for (i=0; i < MAX_THREAD_COUNT_PER_PROCESS; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i].valid == 1)
            {
                line = buffer[i].line;
                k = buffer[i].line_num;
                buffer[i].valid = 0;
                printf ("Thread %u checking line %u - which is %s \n", local_thread_num, k, buffer[i].line);
                break;
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(buffer_mutex);

        i = 0, j = 0, wordcount_in_line = 0;
        while ( (*(line+i) != '\n') )
        {

            // Extract word
            if ( (*(line+i) == ' '))
            {
                // NUll terminate the word to make it a string
                *(word+j) = '\0';
                // Compare
                //printf ("Thread %u checking line %u - word number %u which is %s \n", local_thread_num, k, wordcount_in_line, word);
                if (strcmp (word, local_string_to_search) == 0) // No double quotes around argv[2]
                {
                    count ++;
                    printf("Thread %u found its local %uth occurence of %s in line %u at word %u \n", local_thread_num, count, word, k, wordcount_in_line);
                }
                // Make j = -1, after increment it will be 0 for new word
                j = -1;
                wordcount_in_line++ ;
            }
            else
            {
                *(word+j) = *(line+i);
            }
            // Increment both i and j to go to next character
            i++; j++;
        }

        if ((*(line + i)) == '\n')
        {
            // If end of line - do the same thing on last word as is for every word
            // NUll terminate the word to make it a string
            *(word + j) = '\0';
            // Compare
            //printf ("Thread %u checking line %u - word number %u which is %s \n", local_thread_num, k, wordcount_in_line, word);
            if (strcmp(word, local_string_to_search) == 0)  // No double quotes around argv[2]
            {
                count++;
                printf("Thread %u found its local %uth occurence of %s in line %u at word %u \n", local_thread_num, count, word, k, wordcount_in_line);
            }
            wordcount_in_line++ ;
        }

    }

    void* status;
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_join (threads[0], &status);

    printf ("Thread %u found %u occurences \n", local_thread_num, count);
    i_pthread_argv->count = count;
    //return (count);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // Declare file *
    FILE* fp;

    // Get file path and open file
    //fp = fopen ("file_name.txt","r");
    fp = fopen (argv[1],"r"); // No "" around argv[1]
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("fopen failed \n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf ("file = %s and string to look for = %s \n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    //fopen_s(&fp, "file_name.txt", "r");

    //Initialize mutex  
    if (pthread_mutex_init(buffer_mutex, NULL))
    printf ("Mutex initialization failed \n");


    // Get number of lines in file
    uint num_threads;
    sscanf(argv[3], "%u", &num_threads);

    // Create threads
    //pthread_t* threads;
    threads = (pthread_t*) malloc (sizeof (pthread_t)*MAX_THREAD_COUNT_PER_PROCESS);

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    uint i = 0;

    read_pthread_argv.fp = fp;
    if ( pthread_create (&threads[0], &attr , read_file, (void*)(&read_pthread_argv) ) == 0) 
    printf("Thread creation %u passed \n", i);

    for ( i = 1; i<num_threads; i++ )
        {

            count_pthread_argv[i].thread_num = i;
            count_pthread_argv[i].string_to_search = argv[2];
            //printf("Reached debugging point 1 \n");
            if ( pthread_create (&threads[i], &attr , count_string, (void*)(&count_pthread_argv[i]) ) == 0) 
            printf("Thread creation %u passed \n", i);
        }
    //printf("Reached debugging point 2 \n");
    // Doubt 2 - How to call pthread_join to wait for completion of multiple threads - 
    // Isnt the for loop executed sequentially and pthread_join in main for thread-2 will be executed after thread-1 exits
    // Wait till all are over

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    void* status;
    int rc;
    for (i = 1; i<num_threads; i++ )
    {
        rc = pthread_join (threads[i], &status);
    }

    uint totalcount = 0;
    for (i = 1; i<num_threads; i++)
    {
        printf ("count_returned = %u \n", count_pthread_argv[i].count);
        totalcount += count_pthread_argv[i].count;
    }
    printf("From main, The file has %s -> %u times", argv[2], totalcount);

    for (i=0; i<MAX_THREAD_COUNT_PER_PROCESS; i++)
    {
        free (buffer[i].line);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(buffer_mutex);

    getchar();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Think about how the multi-threaded version might work. Let's say 100 lines in the file, 4 threads. How many times would you call `fgets` on the same file pointer in that case? How many would succeed? How many that didn't succeed would you catch since you have absolutely no error checking? Your approach isn't going to work. You need to have some synchronization and maintain context for each thread so it can seek to the right place in the file and read after the other threads have moved the file pointer. This is not a trivial task.

Comment: Is that really an MCVE ([MCVE])?  It looks a bit big.  Tip: don't extend character strings across line breaks with backslash-newline.  Use string concatenation.  Writing `"string 1"    "string 2"` is valid C (since C90) and the two strings could be on separate lines in the source code.  Note that there is no operator separating those string — just white space (comments count as white space too).

Comment: It may help to think about how you would do this if the contents of the file was read into an array of strings in memory. That alleviates the synchronization issue. You might also have more success with one producer thread reading data and parceling it out to consumer threads to count.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - I have made changes for the way you told. I am still having segmentation fault. The code is updated above. I checked the fault does not occur while reading the file into strings. Its somewhere else.

Comment: Your code above doesn't compile. You missed some places you tried to comment something out. If I was you I'd get rid of all of the dynamic memory allocations and use fixed buffers of `MAX_LINE_LENGTH`.   The most obvious problem is this sequence of lines in the file reading loop: `buffer[i].line = (char*) malloc (line_length); buffer[i].line = line;` You allocate memory then immediately overwrite the value with a pointer to your scratch variable. The next time you read a line all other lines will point to the new one as well. Use `strcpy` to copy data.